# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to alter the value of an item in an object. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'completed' of object
>   '[object Object]'

Here is the model of the object:

```
 export interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    completed: boolean;
}
```

I have an object with values where `completed` is `false`

Now, what I want to do is change the value of completed on some function call

```
onClick(item: Item){
  item.completed = true;
  console.log(item);
}
```

Calling the above method is giving me this

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'completed' of object
>   '[object Object]'

How can I change the value of `completed` in the object?

Comment: Looks like you've editted the question to remove the original code snippet - how did you define the object exactly?

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? Did you specify that the object should use the interface?

Comment: @Edric yes it was specified to use the interface! I am using ``"typescript": "~3.4.5"``

Comment: Could you add how you've defined the variable exactly?

Comment: @Edric `` let item: Item = {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Everglades',
      completed: false
    }``

Comment: How are you passing the `item` variable to the `onClick` method?

Comment: @Edric I do a loop through a list of items. I get the item from an array of objects (Item[]).

Comment: Please consider editing the code in this question so as to constitute a true [mcve] which demonstrates the issue you are seeing.  The error you are mentioning is a runtime error that can't happen to a fresh object literal like `{completed: false}`.  Something somewhere had to make the property non-writable, for example via something like [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).  We need more relevant code to reproduce this issue.